# Protecting Polarized capacitor from reverse voltage

Tags: capacitor, protection, reverse-polarity

I have a circuit with a P-channel MOSFET based reverse voltage protection. Will the polarized capacitor be "safe" if a reverse voltage is applied to the below circuit?

I've mocked it up in simulations and it seems that putting a positive voltage (V+) on the GND pad will bring everything from the ground pad J2 to MOSFET source pin to V+ (no current flowing). Presumably in that case, both sides of cap C1 are at V+ voltage and therefore there's not a reverse voltage situation and the cap should be fine.

Is this understanding of the situation correct?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please add a Zener diode across GS. Also, please simulate your circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fine, if Q1 does not turn on then C1's terminals would be at the same potential and it would not be polarized the wrong way. This also only works if GS and DS voltages are not exceeded on the FET.